# How do I insert UITextField in to UITableView after button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

In master view application xcode generates ready app with table view and the plus button. I want to change that button to to add a new cell but not with the date as it is by default. I want to add two text fields like label->textfield, label->textfield.

In code I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self     action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (GCDetailViewController *) [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
```

and the function:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender{    
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }    
    [_objects insertObject:[UITextField alloc] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Thank You

Comment: format your code.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to think about this is model-view-controller (MVC).  `_objects` is your model representing whatever the user thinks is in the table.  Say it's a to-do list, then objects could be an array of NSObject subclass you create like TodoItem.

You would insert new TodoItems into `_objects`, then tell your table (the "View" in MVC) that it's model has changed.  You can do that imprecisely using `reloadData`, or in a more targeted fashion as your code suggests, calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` - but that call must be sandwiched between tableView `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

You can add textFields in code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, or in the cell prototype in storyboard.  Your table view datasource should always refer to objects... i.e. `numberOfRows` answers `self.objects.count`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets:

```
TodoItem *item = [self.objects objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
```

and uses that item's properties to initialize the textField's text.  Also, incidentally, objects should be declared like this:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;
```

...and your code should refer to `self.objects` almost everywhere (not _objects).  Initializing it on the first insert is too late, because the table needs it to be valid right-away, as soon as it's visible.  Usually, a good practice is a "lazy" init replacing the synthesized getter...

```
- (NSMutableArray *)objects {

    if (!_objects) {    // this one of just a few places where you should refer directly to the _objects
        _objects = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find using the free Sensible TableView framework really helpful here. Here is some sample code to illustrate how you'd do this using the framework:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender{ 
   SCTableViewSection *section = [self.tableViewModel sectionAtIndex:0];
   [section addCell:[SCTextFieldCell cellWithText:@"Enter Text"]];
}
```

Comes in really handy for these types of situations.